# my SD card is not working on my phone

Tags: external-sd

my SD card is not working on my phone, it keeps on appearing damaged SD card each tym I insert it but then it works on other people's phone , it seems the problem is with my phone, ***Samsung s3 mini, please could someone help me out?

Comment: Try checking for memory and data errors in Windows PC...

Answer (score 0):

At first bring some another sd card and try it out in your phone to make sure that your sd card is damaged or not.
 If the new SD card too shows damaged SD card then there is a problem in your SD card.
 And if the new one works perfectly, put the damaged SD card in your Computer using Adapters and through Disk Management repair your SD card.
It may recover your SD card.